# How to user order by clause to get records correctly with data in shape of 01/2020

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I have some file's records with the number like 01/2020, 02/2020 up to so on and I have used order by clause to get the records in order by these numbers but it return correctly from 01/2020 to 10/2020 then it show me 100/2020 is there a solution? kindly share with me.

Comment: you may having field type varchar.

Comment: field type is varchar..

Comment: try as `ORDER BY ABS(YourField)`

Comment: is there a solution?

Comment: I assume there will be data like `01/2021, 02/2021 ... 100/2022` etc. in the future? So this is actually `running_no/year`, correct? If so, `ABS()` alone won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct whereby the format of this record is `running_no/year` then you need to extract the year to include in order by. Consider example below.

If data is like this:

```
+----------+
|   Value  |
+----------+
| 01/2020  |
| 02/2020  |
| 10/2020  |
| 100/2020 |
| 01/2021  |
| 10/2021  |
+----------+
```

Whereby the 4 digits at the back represent running year, then you can extract the year from if in a few ways. Here I'm showing two example using `RIGHT()` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.

```
example 1:
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RIGHT(Value,4) ASC, ABS(Value) ASC;

example 2:
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Value,'/',-1) ASC, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Value,'/',1) ASC;
```

There are more ways to achieve this as long as you can be certain it will return the result the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved by using `ORDER BY ABS(MyField)`